# How to add additional metadata to a zip file using a bash script?

Tags: bash, zip, metadata

I can do the following  in a bash script to create a zip file.

```
#!/bin/bash

zip -r my_folder_zipped.zip ./folder_to_zip
```

In the above bash script, how can I add an additional readable metadata with a line which says like "This is created by Chris" to the zip file?

Is there a Zip command I could use here on the .zip created?

**Context:**
https://superuser.com/questions/337112/zip-file-with-metadata

I have access to `zipdetails` command in the bash script which is a way to read the metadata but how do I add a custom metadata to my zip file from the bash script.
https://www.networkworld.com/article/3333640/zipping-files-on-linux-the-many-variations-and-how-to-use-them.html

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to add a comment to the zip file, use the `-z` option.
If you want a comment associated with an individual entry in the zip file, use the `-c` option

If you mean more than that, you need to give more detail on what *exactly* do you mean by metadata?

[Full Disclosure: I'm the author of zipdetails]

Comment: You see, I have posted a bash script in my question. If you just show how to add a comment using `zip -z` in one liner, thats what I need. Thanks for citing at `zip -z`

Comment: Not quite - the `-z` and `-c` options read from stdin, so you would use something like this  `echo I am the author | zip -z my_folder_zipped.zip`. Alternatively, if you just run `zip -z my_folder_zipped.zip` it will prompt you for a comment